# How to read all input row at one time from csv file in selenium java webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fetching the input from CSV file, There are lots of input in the CSV file so I need to fetch all row at one time from cell 1.

```
 CSVReader reader = null;
 int numberOfRows = 0;

        try {
            reader = new CSVReader ( new FileReader ( Excelpath ) );
            String[] cell = reader.readNext ();
            int i = 0;


            while (( cell = reader.readNext () ) != null) {
                if (i >= 8) {
                    barcode[ i - 8 ] = cell[ 1 ];

                }
                i++;
            }

            numberOfRows = i - 1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
```

Comment: Please specifiy what you are trying to achieve with your code, and what part is not working as intended.

Comment: And attach your CSV or screen of it.